# The function for changing the icon does not work marker.setIcon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I make a map, and I need to change the label icon after clicking on the label

I tried to pass

```
marker.setIcon(url:'https://seoma.com/bitrix/templates/aspro_next/images/home/metka_2.png');

     markers.forEach(function(marker,i){
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', 
    (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
     return function() {

 infowindow_array.forEach(function(e,i){
  if(e!=infowindow){

  e.close();

    }
 })
markers.forEach(function(marker_,i_){
  if(marker_!=e){
         if( typeof 
     marker_.default_icon_ !== 'undefined'){
    marker_.setIcon('https://seoma.com/bitrix/templates/aspro_next/images/home/metka_2.png');
  }
    }else{
     marker.setIcon('https://seoma.com/bitrix/templates/aspro_next/images/home/metka_.png');     
    }
 });

  infowindow.setContent(content);
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
 };
})(marker,content,infowindow));

}
```

After the clicking on the mark of the mark, the mark should change. But for the place of this one more icon is added and it turns out like this http://prntscr.com/ojwwt3

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to the marker itself. Here is a sample fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/Ly1qu7e9/2/

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    marker.setIcon("https://i.imgur.com/YtSE62r.png");
  });
```